# Fetch all user's input (<pattern>input</pattern>) in .aiml file and append it on a list

Tags: python, flask, aiml

Currently my task is to get all the user's input inside the .aiml file, and **append** it to a list using Python3. Below is the code:

**topic.aiml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<aiml version = "1.0.1" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
   <category>
      <pattern>HELLO ALICE</pattern>
      <template>
         Hello User
      </template>
   </category>

   <category>
      <pattern>HOW ARE YOU</pattern>
      <template>
         I'm fine
      </template>
   </category>

   <category>
      <pattern>WHAT ARE YOU DOING</pattern>
      <template>
         Coding
      </template>
   </category>

   <category>
      <pattern>WHERE YOU FROM</pattern>
      <template>
         Manila
      </template>
   </category>
</aiml>
```

**test.py**

```
@extract.route('/')
def index_page():
    folder = 'templates/topic.aiml'
    data_set = []
    with open(folder, 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    return data
```

Return value is: **HELLO ALICE HOW ARE YOU WHAT ARE YOU DOING WHERE YOU FROM**, which is correct. But I don't know how will I append it to **data_set**

I'm just to new to this kind of task that the team gave to me. Much appreciated if someone know how to manipulate this one. Thanks!

Below is the result.

[Return value from topic.aiml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wUkX.png)

Comment: hi. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'append it to data_set', but it sounds like all you need is `data_set.append(data)` just before your return statement.

Comment: @Stael I wanna do it something like this: data_set = ['HELLO ALICE', 'HOW ARE YOU', 'WHAT ARE YOU DOING', 'WHERE YOU FROM']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output you want truly is `HELLO ALICE HOW ARE YOU WHAT ARE YOU DOING WHERE YOU FROM`, your result is ***Misleading*** you.

I am going to take some of the ambiguous information in your question with my interpretation of it.

What you are currently doing is just taking your file, removing the line-breaks, and returning everything else.

I ran this program;

```
from flask import Flask

extract = Flask(__name__)

@extract.route('/')
def index_page():
    folder = 'templates/topic.aiml'
    data_set = []
    with open(folder, 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    return data

extract.run()
```

And this is how it looks in the browser;

[image]

What you instead need to do is to parse the text and find what's inside the `pattern` tags. For that I recommend using BeautifulSoup;

```
from flask import Flask
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

extract = Flask(__name__)

@extract.route('/')
def index_page():
    folder = 'templates/topic.aiml'
    with open(folder, 'r') as myfile:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile.read(), 'html.parser')

    data_set = [match.text for match in soup.find_all("pattern")]
    data = " ".join(data_set)

    return data

extract.run()
```

Comment: You're the man bro! This is actually the result set I needed. Thanks! Much appreciated your help.

Comment: What if I wanted to exclude <pattern> tags inside a <topic> tag. For example: <topic name="botquestions"> <category> <pattern>MY DOGS NAME IS *</pattern> <template> That is interesting that you have a dog named <set name="dog"><star/></set> </template> </category> </topic> 

Those <pattern> tags inside a <topic> shouldn't be included on the result set, given the <topic> tags have a **name** attribute